# Objects with the same name, what does that mean?

Tags: objective-c

I thought I had a decent understanding of objects, but I guess not. What happens when two objects are the same name? They are both pointing to the same location in memory? So if I had one class that said:

```
SomeClass *someObject = [SomeClass new];
someObject.text = @"test";
```

And another class instantiates the same object with the same name:

```
SomeClass *someObject = [SomeClass new];
someObject.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This would modify the same object to be a red text that says "test" right ?

Thanks!
~Carpetfizz

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean with *This would modify the same object to be a red text that says "test" right ?*

Comment: `text` and `textColor` have different types...Anyway, no, you cannot do that.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those two pointers point to two different objects in the memory. It doesn't matter if they have the same name. They were allocated and initialized separately in two different classes.

Btw, you should never use the new method to allocate and initalize the object. The new message is discouraged, as allocation and initialization are two different processes. You should use this instead:

```
SomeClass *someObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: Can you provide a citation for the assertion that `+new` is deprecated? It's not marked as such in the headers or docs, and works just fine (as long as you're not needing a special `initWithFoo:` initializer.

Comment: Deprecated is a bit strong, "discouraged" would be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  Just because two variables happen to share the same name does not mean they share the same memory location.  When this compiles, the compiler strips the variable names (but not the class names) and calculates memory offsets and messages instead of names and classes.  Besides, as a local variable, as soon as they pass out of scope -most likely at the end of each function that created them- they will be destroyed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

### No. You can't do that.

Any modern-day compiler will attempt to strangle you before compiling that code - for that exact reason: It doesn't know what to do!

Even if you *could* get the compiler to make it work, just because the two objects have the same name doesn't mean they have the same memory address.

Comment: What exactly will a compiler complain about? That's legal code, just not with the behavior Carpetfizz expects.

Comment: @andyvn22 Well, the compiler wouldn't know which object to modify. Hence an error coming out of my copy of Xcode.

Comment: "...And *another class* instantiates..." The two `someObject`s are not in the same scope.